# Como adquirir el width padre

Tags: html, css

***Si tengo lo siguiente:***

```css
#t {width:300px;height:300px;background-color:dimgray;border-radius:150px;z-index:1;}

#ticket{
height:100px;
top: 35%;
position: relative;
background-color:white;
width:300px;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
<div id="ticket"></div>
</div>
```

El div `t` contiene al div `ticket`, entonces ¿cómo podría hacer para que el div `hijo ticket`, herede su width, sin `js`?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como denegar que sobrepase el div padre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101854/como-denegar-que-sobrepase-el-div-padre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días amigo puedes usar la propiedad inherit en el estilo aplicado

```css
#t {width:300px;height:300px;background-color:dimgray;border-radius:150px;z-index:1;}

#ticket{
height:100px;
top: 35%;
position: relative;
background-color:white;
width:inherit;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
<div id="ticket"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que es inherit?

Comment: inherit es un valor que puedes pasar a la propiedad width para que herede el valor del padre lo puedes usar en todas las propiedades como backgroundcolor etc en este caso heredara el ancho del padre

Answer (score 3):

El width del hijo debe de ser 100% para que siempre tome el ancho del padre

```css
#t {width:200px;height:200px;background-color:dimgray;border-radius:150px;z-index:1;}

#ticket{
height:100px;
top: 35%;
position: relative;
background-color:white;
width:100%;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
<div id="ticket"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo con darle un `width:100%` al elemento hijo se redimensionará siempre al tamaño que tenga su elemento padre. Saludos.