# Como denegar que sobrepase el div padre

Tags: html, css

***Si tengo un div dentro de otro, como esto:***

```css
#padre{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:lightpink;
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:15%;
border-radius:150px;
border: 2px solid purple;
}
#hijo{
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:purple;
position:relative;
top:35%;
left:0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
<div id="hijo"></div>
</div>
```

*Como debería hacer para que el contenido del `div hijo`, no salga del `div padre`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

podrías agregar `overflow: hidden;` en `div#padre`, de esa forma todos los hijos que sobrepasen al padre no se muestren.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Así es como me quedo.*